How to use a USB cord and a rooted Pixel 4 tablet to root and jailbreak other devices?
I have a Pixel 4 tablet that is rooted with a functional USB and port. I'm trying to figure out how I can use the USB cord and hook it up to the same device that isn't rooted, clean out all of its operating systems, and make it to where it is rooted and install whatever I want. I have no idea what tools I need to use or how to use them if I do.
Can I get any help with this and some educated tips on how to go about doing this?

Possibly related: How to manually root a phone?

So you want to use one rooted Pixel 4 to root another Pixel. The main problem I see is that I am not sure if you can use fastboot from one device to another. Fastboot is essential to perform the bootloader unlocking and for flashing a recovery or modified bootloader.

Agreed. It may be far simpler to buy a cheap Linux or Windows mini-PC, simply to have access to the usual tools for the job. They start at around $200.

@JohnDallman That is way cheaper possible. You just need a Raspberry Pi (1,2,3,4,5,...). If you use it remotely via SSH you could even use it from an Android tablet and the PI headless (no screen or keyboard).

@Robert: I didn't consider RPis because Google don't provide their Platform Tools for ARM Linux, and having those tools us usually important.

Platform Tools to run on Android available here, but with less of a guarantee than Google's builds.
